# SNTP timeout after 15 seconds but default is supposed to be 68 sec

Tags: macos, ntp

Using sntp to query an NTP server times out after just 15 sec.

```
Stevens-MacBook-Air:~ Steve$ sntp -d time.nist.gov
Starting to read KoD file /var/db/ntp-kod...
sntp sendpkt: Sending packet to 2610:20:6f15:15::27... Packet sent.
sntp recvdata: select() reached timeout (15 sec), aborting.
sntp recvpkt failed: -1.
Server unusable
on_wire failed for server 2610:20:6f15:15::27!
sntp sendpkt: Sending packet to 216.229.0.179... Packet sent.
sntp recvdata: select() reached timeout (15 sec), aborting.
sntp recvpkt failed: -1.
Server unusable
on_wire failed for server 216.229.0.179!
```

According to [sntp documentation](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/sntp.html) and man page for sntp, default is supposed to be 68 seconds. Is this a bug sntp installed in OS 10.11.6?

Answer (score 2):

Apple's manual page says the default is 5 seconds, but I'm seeing the same 15 second timeout as you in practice. I'd file a bug against the documentation to make it match (if you want) and then specify the timeout you want on macOS:

```
sntp --timeout 68 -d time.nist.gov
```

Comment: Where did you see manual page that says default in 5 sec. From terminal "man sntp" returns: 
` -t seconds, --timeout=seconds
              Specify  the  number  of  seconds  to wait for broadcasts.  This
              option takes an integer number as  its  argument.   The  default
              seconds for this option is:
                   68'

Comment: @Steve I just right click on the command in terminal and let the system open the man page for `sntp` in a new window.